# Create small squares on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a solution in order to create small squares figure that I will incorporate into a bigger figer. So for instance if we take this dataframe;

```
  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 0 1 1
```

I would like to create 2 plots :

for row1

[image]

and

for row2

[image]
Here is the data

```
data<-structure(list(a = c(1, 1), 
    b = c(1, 0), c = c(1, 
    1), d = c(1, 1
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

does someone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to "is there a way without transforming to a long format" - well, not really for ggplot2. If you want to use ggplot, you will want to map your variables to an aesthetic, which will take *columns*, not rows. But there is no real issue here - you can just create a new data frame and add this to the other plot.

Another option instead of tiles is to draw points in the shape of squares. I take from your question that you want to indeed create separate plots. I am using patchwork here for the convenience of showing the output, but you can of course leave them separate. The advantage of this approach - you would not be constricted to use `coord_fixed`.

Apparently you also want to draw nothing when the value is 0. Best to replace with NA, so ggplot will ignore this point.

[Thanks user GordonShumway for the colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591491/7941188)!

```r
  library(ggplot2)
  library(patchwork)
  
  df<-structure(list(a = c(1, 1), b = c(1, 0), c = c(1,  1), d = c(1, 1 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  df_long <- data.frame(t(df))
  df_long$colors <- c("#53ae32", "#2e76b5", "#f2d355", "#d23c28")
  df_long[df_long == 0] <- NA
  
  p_ls <- 
    purrr::map(1:nrow(df), function(i){
      ggplot(df_long, aes_string(1:4, paste0("X", i))) +
        geom_point(aes(color = colors), shape = 15, size = 20, show.legend = FALSE) +
        scale_color_identity() +
        coord_cartesian(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
        theme_void() +
        theme(plot.margin = margin(r = 1, l = 1, unit = "in")) +
        ggtitle(paste("Plot", i))
    })
  wrap_plots(p_ls) +plot_layout(nrow  = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to convert the data into a tidy (long) format:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1<-structure(list(a = c(1, 1), 
                     b = c(1, 0), c = c(1, 
                                        1), d = c(1, 1
                                        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


df1_tidy <- df1 %>% 
  rowid_to_column("rowID") %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "colID", values_to= "value", -rowID) %>% 
  mutate(rowID = factor(rowID, levels = sort(unique(rowID), decreasing = T)))
```

Then to plot you can use `geom_tile` with `coord_fixed` to make sure you end up with squares.

```
ggplot(df1_tidy, aes(x = colID, y = rowID)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = value*0.75,height = value *0.75 , fill = colID)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#53ae32", "#2e76b5", "#f2d355", "#d23c28")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Or in base R:

```
#genrate blank plot with correct dimensions
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(-5,0), bty="n", xaxt='n',yaxt='n',  ann=FALSE, )
clrs <- c("#53ae32", "#2e76b5", "#f2d355", "#d23c28")
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df1)){
    cat(i,j, v, "\n")
    v <- df1[i,j]
    rect(xleft = j, xright = j+0.9, ybottom = -i, ytop = -i-0.9, col = ifelse(v==0, "white", clrs[j]), border = NA) 
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, is there not a way to not transform it as tidy long format ?

Comment: Because I need to keep the dataframe as it is since I also need to keep other informations stored in a colum for each row.

Comment: @chippycentra you can still create and use a separate data frame?